# How to remove white background of a jpg completely on gimp?

Tags: gimp

I managed to use the 'fuzzy' tool to remove the slightly off white background. However, I want the shape itself to change. For instance, when I drop shadow on the image the shadow is rectangular on the previous outline, of the jpg, not the new rectangular shape. Also, Layers underneath are not visible where I just used the fuzzy tool to remove the background.

I guess using the fuzzy tool and pressing delete just gives a white background on the selected region? I want it to completely remove the background and make it transparent, how do I do that?

Comment: This should be asked at https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Jpeg does not support transparency.  Use another file type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906144/transparent-background-in-jpeg-image

Comment: You can make an area transparent by adding an alpha channel (under layer->transparency), then select the area that you want to be transparent, then do edit->clear.